# negative log result in c

Tags: c, math

I need to get the natural log of a number (between 0 and 1) in C. But the natural log function  in C gives an undefined error if the result is negative.

What is the way around this?

EDIT: Sorry folks , my code had flipped the input and output , and I wasn't able to spot it , thanks for the quick help, sorry for my obvious stupidity!

Comment: Do you have code exhibiting the problem?

Comment: Can you show example code?  It would be rather strange behaviour if log gave an error for values in the range (0, 1).

Comment: undefined error?  How does it give it to you?  Is it when you run the program or when you compile it?  Show your code?

Comment: EDIT: Sorry folks , my code had flipped the input and output , and I wasn't able to spot it , thanks for the quick help, sorry for my obvious stupidity!

Answer (score 5):

No it doesn't.  It gives an error (or rather, returns NaN) if the *input* is negative.  The standard library `log` function works perfectly for inputs between zero and one.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry folks , my code had flipped the input and output , and I wasn't able to spot it , thanks for the quick help, sorry for my obvious stupidity!

Answer (score 2):

Logarithms don't have a real solution (using `real` in its mathematical sense) for negative numbers: the log of a negative number is a complex value, which cannot be represented by a C `double`. So the standard library won't give a result for this: you'll need to find a complex maths library or write your own complex log function.

**Edit:** most readers will have noticed, I hope, that I have (perhaps wrongly!) assumed that the OP means that the error occurs when the **input** is negative, not the result!

Comment: EDIT: Sorry folks , my code had flipped the input and output , and I wasn't able to spot it , thanks for the quick help, sorry for my obvious stupidity!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean if the *result* is negative, or the *input*? `log()` should have no trouble returning negative results. Show your code and output.

If you mean the *input* is negative, test that your input is greater than zero before calling `log()`. There's no sensible answer to the log of zero or negative numbers.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry folks , my code had flipped the input and output , and I wasn't able to spot it , thanks for the quick help, sorry for my obvious stupidity!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean that the error happens when you compile the program? Then make sure that you add

```
#include <math.h>
```

and then add -lm when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

How do you detect the error?

None of the standard C library functions sets `errno` to zero, so if you want to detect an error, you have to do something like:

```
errno = 0;
double d = log(0.25);
if (errno != 0)
    ...handle error...
```

If you don't set `errno` to 0, you may get any left-over value from any previous system call.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry folks , my code had flipped the input and output , and I wasn't able to spot it , thanks for the quick help, sorry for my obvious stupidity!